# Using Selenium Webdriver to do an action if a condition is met

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am using selenium to perform repetitive tasks on a website - a very useful feature for automating web tasks.

I am stuck on how to perform an action only if certain text is present on the page. Is this possible?

I do not want the lack of text to break the test case - only to bypass the action.

I have the Flow Control plugin too, but havent figured out how to make this do any more.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any code we could look at? See [Ask] if you need help.

Answer (score 3):

In Java you can make a method that returns true or false whether an element is present or not :

```
public boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
    try {
        return driver.findElement(by) != null;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And concerning the text you want to find you can do :

```
if(isElementPresent(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Some text')]"))){
        // Do your tests here
}
```